# 5-year EFS > 5-year OS

Tags: survival, censoring, kaplan-meier

I had a data of 24 cancer patients; their 5-year overall survival (i.e. event as death) was around 57%, however, when I calculated 5-year event-free survival for the same cohort, defining the event as death or relapse, I got 61%.

I have scrutinized the data and I am 99.99% sure there is nothing wrong with it, and I could totally see how this could result from the survival function. I thought Cross Validated community might give more meaningful insights.

Is there anything wrong with this? Did that happen to you before? If so, how do you report it?

[image: Kaplan Meier for OS and EFS for the 24 cases]

Of notice, this didn't happen anymore when the follow up was updated and 2 more cases were included. I also noticed that all the cases that died had also experienced an event before death.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

The pattern of events and censoring over time accounts for this small discrepancy. Remember that the size of a step down in a Kaplan-Meier curve, at each event, is based on the previous survival fraction and the number still at risk at the time of the event.

In your data there are 5 censorings in both curves at around 20-25 months. That's more than 20% of your initial cohort lost to follow up over a short period of time. These censorings occur after the 5th event in the event-free survival curve, but after only the 3rd death. The sizes of the 4th and 5th steps down in the overall-survival curve (with only 13 resp. 12 at risk by my count) are thus larger than the 4th and 5th steps down in the event-free survival curve (with 18 resp. 17 at risk), taking the overall survival curve to a lower survival fraction than the event-free survival curve *after the same number of events*. The pattern of lower overall survival than event-free survival *after the same number of events* continues thereafter. Once the number of events has reached 8 in both curves, the overall survival curve remains a bit lower.

As the most useful information in a survival curve is provided by the events, you might think about this as those 5 particular censorings having lost more information about overall survival (5 censorings after only 3 events) than about event-free survival (5 censorings after 5 events). In any case, the discrepancy is minor: a 4 percentage-point discrepancy with only 24 cases to start is pretty much just +/- one case.